# A-frame 1.3.0 issue with aframe-environment-component

Tags: components, aframe

[image]Having an interesting issue using aframe-environment-component in A-frame 1.3.0 where the geometry in at least 'forest' appears fractured.

I haven't tried all of the presets and have been using 'arches' for my demo which does appear darker than expect. It looks like some geometry matrices have been updated recently and may have something to do with it.

Comment: Does it happen it [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye6gfk72/)?

Comment: The fiddle works. It appears to be an issue with the Chrome browser on my machine. It works in both Firefox and Safari. I've tried reinstalling chrome but no change. Other people have viewed in chrome with no issue so it has something to do with my version on my machine. Thank you for reaching out to help, much appreciated.

Comment: once had a similar bug with webgl particles when my 1060GTX drivers went out of date